# Unit spheres for different distance metrics (2D) in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am trying to plot unit spheres for different distance metrics (2D) in R.

I would like to visualize L_0.1, L_0.5, L_1, L_2, L_4, L_10, L_infinity.

I hope to do something like the following in R but with more metrics.

[image]

The following R code is my attempt.

```
################ Different metrics ##################
fun <- function(x,p=.5){ 
(abs(x)^.5)}
fun1 <- function(x,p=.5){ 
  (2-abs(x)^.5)}

fun2 <- function(x,p=.1){ 
  (abs(x)^.1)}
fun3 <- function(x,p=.1){ 
  (2-abs(x)^.1)}

fun4 <- function(x,p=1){ 
  (abs(x)^1)}
fun5 <- function(x,p=1){ 
  (2-abs(x)^1)}

fun6 <- function(x,p=2){ 
  (abs(x)^2)}
fun7 <- function(x,p=2){ 
  (2-abs(x)^2)}

fun8 <- function(x,p=4){ 
  (abs(x)^4)}
fun9 <- function(x,p=4){ 
  (2-abs(x)^4)}

fun10 <- function(x,p=10){ 
  (abs(x)^10)}
fun11 <- function(x,p=10){ 
  (2-abs(x)^10)}


plot(fun1,1,-1,ylim=c(2,-0),xlim = c(1,-1))   
plot(fun,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun2,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun3,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun4,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun5,-1,1,add=T) 
plot(fun6,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun7,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun8,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun9,-1,1,add=T) 
plot(fun10,-1,1,add=T)      
plot(fun11,-1,1,add=T)      
##########################################################
```

I am not sure about the function I create. I mean (2-abs(x)). If you notice the original plot I attached in the question centered at zero (y-axis).

Is my code right to reproduce the same plot in the question? and how to give each metrics different colors?

Comment: Are you taking distances as the n-th root of sums of coordinates to the n-th power?

Comment: @42, I performed this formula but without sum "sum(abs(x)^p)", however, I do not know If I am right or not. I would like to have the same idea the figure I attached in the question.

Comment: Looks right for squared and higher powers of distances. Are you getting a square and a circle for a 2d sphere at L1 and L2?

Comment: @42-, Yes, but mine does not centroid at the origin as the figure above. Also, I need to write 2-abs(x) to get the right plot, which I do not know why?  In addition, I cannot deal with the infinity distance.

Comment: Then you need to raise multivariate differences to the pth power. The second question makes no sense to me. You question is nsot reproducible.

Comment: If you want to color the lines, use the `col` argument of `plot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create some generic functions and pass them directly to a plotting function through a `lapply` loop:

For example you can make two generic functions for every `p`:

```
## The generic functions for every p and x
fun.generic1 <- function(p, x) {
    return(abs(x)^p)
}
fun.generic2 <- function(p, x) {
    return(2-abs(x)^p)
}
```

And a plotting function (using `curve` rather than `plot` to pass `x` as a function):

```
## The curve wrapping function
fun.plot <- function(p) {
    curve(fun.generic1(p, x), y = c(-1, 1), add = TRUE)
    curve(fun.generic2(p, x), y = c(-1, 1), add = TRUE)
}
```

You can then create a vector of all the values of `p` you want to plot (including `Inf`):

```
## All the p values
p_vector <- c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 10, Inf)
```

Then plot an empty plot with the x and y limits defined:

```
## Empty plot
plot(NULL, ylim = c(2, -0), xlim = c(1, -1), xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
```

And plot all the parameters using a simple `lapply` (the results are saved in a `silent` object to not jam your `R` console):

```
## Plot all the parameters
silent <- lapply(p_vector, fun.plot)
```

Bonus: you can also wrap all that into a single function that is more elegant:

```
## Wrapping function
plot.everything <- function(p_vector) {
    plot(NULL, ylim = c(2, -0), xlim = c(1, -1), xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
    lapply(p_vector, fun.plot)
    return(invisible())
} 

## Plotting the vector directly
plot.everything(c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 10, Inf))
```

[image: example]

Comment: You can add the colors or line types directly to the `curve` function as additional arguments (you might need to use a `mapply` rather than `lapply` loop if you end up with too many arguments). And for your first comment, I'm not sure what you mean. The code you've provided does not reproduce the attached plot. Could you please edit the code?

Comment: I mean that in a generic function you imitate mine (abs(x),2-abs(x)) which I do not know if it is right or not to generate the same plot in the question. Have a look at y-axis in your plot and the question plot, yours centered at 1 while the question plot at zero.

Comment: Guillerm, according to colors, when I write for example the argument col="red" or col=c("red" ,..., etc), it assigns same colors to all p, but I want diffrent colors for diffrent p. Also If I did this and then I used mapply, the code does not work.